# How to add team members in MS Team using Graph API?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am using Microsoft Graph API to create a team and add team members in MS Teams. I am following this [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/teams_api_overview) for the same:

This is what I'm doing to achieve overall behaviour:

1. Create an office 365 group. No issues here.
2. Create an MS Team under the group created in step 1. This also works fine.
3. Add members to office 365 group created in step 1. Works well.
4. Add same members as team members in MS Team created in step 2. Doesn't work.

I am using below code to add team members:

```
public static void AddMemberToTeam(string userId, string groupId) 
{
            var endpoint = $"{GRAPH_ROOT_URI}groups/{groupId}/members/$ref";
        var content = new Member { ODataId = $"{GRAPH_ROOT_URI}directoryObjects/{userId}" };
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, endpoint);
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", TOKEN);
            request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
}
```

While the response returned from last statement is as per the documentation (204 No Content), members are not getting added to the team. I don't find much help available in the community on Ms Teams graph API.

[Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_post_members) to add team members:

PS: I am using office 365 developer account and I have given all the needed permissions to the admin user.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting **Not Found** error because in Json Payload you are passing ODataId, where as the API call expects it to be @odata.id.

Here are two possible solutions:

1. Update the content to following:

   ```
   var contentJSON = $"{{ \"@odata.id\": \"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/directoryObjects/{userId}\" }}";
   request.Content = new StringContent(contentJSON, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
   ```
2. You can updat your class set @odata.id as Json Property name:

   ```
       class Member
   {
       [JsonProperty("@odata.id")]
       public string ODataId { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm using the exact same class definition that you have mentioned in option 2. However, the issue seems to be resolved after switching from developer account to a licensed office 365 account.